# Template function that accepts temporaries by value and non-temporaries by reference?

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference, c++03

I would like to have

```
template <class T>
void foo(T &t);
```

to be able to accept temporaries as well, without compromising on accepting other objects by reference and calling non-const methods on them. Possible in C++03?

I realize I could possibly force the user to declare all methods of their objects as `const`, and all members as `mutable` and then use a `const T &t` reference, but that's an ugly workaround.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that `foo` would try to modify these temporaries?  Why?

Comment: Somehow your subject (the part with "by value") doesn't fit with the rest of your question description...

Comment: In C++11 that is what universal references are for... but that is not a feature present in C++03

Comment: Why do you want this? As David mentions, C++11 had to make major revisions to the language to support this scenario (single template function accepts rvalues and lvalues and can distinguish between them), so if you want to emulate it you'll have a better chance of getting an answer by stating your requirements. Otherwise you're effectively asking to emulate rvalue references in C++03, which is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second function that takes the const type reference, and makes a copy for the non-const type reference.

```
template <class T>
void foo (T &t);

template <class T>
void foo (const T &x) {
    T copy(x);
    foo(copy);
}
```

A demonstration can be found [here](http://ideone.com/3I6hsv).

This technique has the limitation that it cannot distinguish a temporary from a true `const` object. The consequence of this is that your original `foo()` would have disallowed itself to be passed a `const` object. This proposal would allow them, and thus you lose some safety that was originally provided. You can compensate for that somewhat by re-naming the const type version of `foo` to be something like `foo_for_temp`. Then, the caller would know the intention of the function.

Comment: What if the non-temporary is of a `const`-qualified type?

Comment: @AndyProwl: The code above cannot distinguish const objects from temporary objects. But Irfy's function prototype wouldn't work on const qualified types anyway.

Comment: Indeed, that means it would compile, while the original function would (and should) not compile when invoked with an argument of a `const`-qualified type.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I am agnostic to the technique. The question was basically: can temporaries be passed by value? My answer is: yes, you make your own copy of them.

Comment: This was an effective solution to my problem, and it worked well in practice. Indeed, I did not need const-qualified objects to be passed.

Answer (score 4):

In C++03 there is no way to deduce whether an argument passed to a function is an lvalue or an rvalue.

I guess this is the reason why the title of your question says "*Accepts temporaries by value*": if such a mechanism existed, you could create a function (template) which determines whether the parameter type should be `T&` or `T`, based on that information.

This is exactly what the type deduction machinery supported in C++11 does:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& t);
//       ^^^
//       lvalue of type A is passed: T = A&, signature = foo(A& t)
//       rvalue of type A is passed: T = A, signature = foo(A&& t)
```

But as mentioned above, this is not possible in C++03 precisely because it lacks a way of determining the value category of an expression.

The possibility you mention (force all objects to have `const` member functions) is not a workaround (not even an ugly one): if the member functions are all `const`, it means `foo()` won't need to alter the state of its input. Which in turn means it could take a `const&`, and problem solved.

You probably meant to make those `const` member functions perform a `const_cast<>` in order to alter the object's state, but then again you could the same inside of `foo()`. The reason why this is a bad idea is that in both cases you can't give in input to `foo()` an object whose type is `const`-qualified, and you may not know whether this is or is not the case.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but I accepted a less general solution (no const-qualified objects passed) that applies to my case.

Comment: I didn't understand the point of &&, but with your explanation it suddenly clicked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

One, but dangerous solution would be to have const T & as function argument and then const_cast<> it to T&. You will have to be careful what you pass to the function as it can easily lead to undefined behavior:

```
template <class T>
void foo(const T &ct)
{
    T &t = const_cast<T>( ct );
    // ...
}
```